# Problems mounting an SMB share in my fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a valid, reachable SMB share on my Windows box, which I can mount with

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.9/C /mnt/WinC -o username=foo,password=bar
```

but isn't mountable from my fstab.  The fstab entry reads

```
//192.168.0.9    /mnt/WinC    credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777    0    0
```

and the credentials file (which has 777 permissions while I get this working) contains

```
username=foo
password=bar
```

but sudo mount -a results in an error, which from a dmesg | tail, shows

```
[225040.991705]  CIFS VFS: No username specified
[225050.991721]  CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

Anyone else seen this issue and managed to resolve it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Install `smbfs`.

Sounds silly that a package could fix this but when you use credentials files, the kernel diverts to the `mount.cifs` command rather than doing the mount itself. This package provides `mount.cifs` so should get you on the road to victory!

**Edit:** As Klaus points out in the comments, for 13.04 and later, you need `cifs-utils`.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks.  I'd assumed smbfs was already installed since I was able to mount it manually.

Comment: Yeah it's crazy. `smbfs` is actually the deprecated predecessor to `cifs` so it's even stranger that the `smbfs` package provides this command.

Comment: Nice explanation :)

Comment: If you're using ubuntu 13.04, you should install cifs-utils instead of smbfs.

Comment: Answered decades ago, I know, but I needed this solution for LTS 12.04 and spent way-too-long searching.

Comment: Still helps installing cifs-utils on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5):

I went mad on 14.04. the credential= option was not mounting the share in fstab although I could mount it "by hand" in the cli. Issue was that the "cifs-utils" package was not installed...

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

and everything was fine...